# Nav drawer widget

Tags: android, widget, navigation-drawer

I want to implement a side drawer widget. I don't know if I am using the right words or not. A small icon will be placed on the left/right side of the screen, if it is swiped, it should open an activity. If I close it, it should remain on the side of the screen until application is closed from the inside. I have seen this in an application and I am posting screen shot too.

Notice the image hint on the left side. Its always there even if we press home button:

[image: Screenshot]

I searched for it but didn't find anything. I guess it's because I am not searching with the correct words maybe? It would be great if I knew the name of this widget.

Comment: its custom drawer menu

Comment: But how is it enabled on every screen? The application is closed, i pushed home button. But this drawer is still there. Upon swipe, it opens the parent activity of the application. Drawer menu remains only until the application is open . Isn't it?

Comment: yes , i miss some understand .